# C++ IDE that autogenerates cmakelists.txt

Tags: c++, ide, makefile, cmake

I'm looking for an IDE that automatically generates a cmake file from the project. Ideally I would like the project to be independent of the IDE. I am mainly working under linux but Windows is a major (and great) OS so ideally it would run on Windows as well. I'm not too bothered about that though as on Windows there is VS :).

Regards

EDIT: Yeah, I sort of see my mistake. I should have asked for an IDE that generates makefiles instead of cmake files since the cmake layer/step becomes useless (if the IDE can directly generate a makefile).

Comment: What about generating native project files for each environment using Premake? http://industriousone.com/premake

Comment: When you say "project" what do you mean?  Because as far as I know VS can only open VS projects, and no linux program can read them.

Comment: Arak: Premake is of no use. A person using a text editor can compile a cmake project. With Premake you need to have one of the IDEs.

Mooing Duck: by project I mean the program comprising of all source files (.cc and .h). Much like a VS C# project.

Comment: I'm not sure this is possible, and it seems like you'd be losing a whole lot of the usefulness and power of CMake anyways.  

It would be a happy surprise, though, if someone could prove me wrong.

Personally, I think emacs is about the best IDE you can get, and it does have a CMake mode (http://www.cmake.org/CMakeDocs/cmake-mode.el) .  Or vim.  I'm not trying to proselytize emacs over vim as much as the use of a good text editor.

Comment: @user931670: Premake can generate makefiles too.

Answer (score 2):

The purpose of CMake is to generate the `Makefiles` and projects that other development environments rely on, so what you're asking seems a little backwards. CMake is exactly the tool that does what you're asking to do, but in a different direction.

That said, KDevelop 4 has the option to use `CMakeLists.txt` files instead of the usual project file, but it doesn't work very well, and I've given up on trying to use it. Instead I edit the `CMakeLists.txt` file by hand - and KDevelop helpfully updates the GUI appropriately to reflect my changes.

Comment: Hmm, I thought that Kdevelop can generate the cmakelists.txt file itself. There isn't much documentation on cmake and from what I've heard the book is pretty much a copy of the online reference docs.

Comment: The book is a copy of the man pages, yeah. And so is the documentation within KDevelop. (But really, that's all the documentation you need.) And yes, KDevelop can generate the `CMakeLists.txt` file, but does so very poorly - I've had it crash the whole IDE repeatedly, letting it manage the file. It's terrible at it and I advise against using it.